# How to set up Varnish in a dedicated server with mutiple IPs and domains?

Tags: apache, caching, centos, cpanel, varnish

I have a dedicated server with many domains. Some domains have their own dedicated IP and some IPs are shared by domains.

I want to set up varnish for all domains and IPs.

Server: CentOS 7.2 with cPanel 11.58

Do you know of any cpanel plugin? or simple code or a efficient method which can setup varnish for all domains/IPs automatically/easily.

After installing varnish, I changed to apache port to "8080". I changed port to "80" in varnish.params and to "8080" in default.vcl. Now varnish works for primary IP and domain of the server.

I tried to modify default.vcl by following method, but after that varnish gives error when I try to load. I am confused and tried so many things to solve it, but unfortunately nothing worked.

```
backend example1 {
    .host = "5.135.166.39";
    .port = "8080";
}

backend example2 {
    .host = "46.105.40.241";
    .port = "8080";
}
sub vcl_recv {

    if (server.ip == "5.135.166.39") {
        set req.backend = example1; 
    } elseif (server.ip == "46.105.40.241") {
        set req.backend = example2;
    } else {
        set req.backend = default;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your conditions by the domain name itself not with its ip. so lets say you have 2 doamins:

`www.foo.com` with `A record` `5.135.166.39`
`www.bar.com` with `A record` `46.105.40.241`

inside `vcl_recv` you need to do the following:

```
if (req.http.host ~ "foo.com") {
    set req.backend = example1;
}

if (req.http.host ~ "bar.com") {
    set req.backend = example2;
}
```

use `~` to match any url that contains `foo.bar` or you can use `== "www.foo.com"` to match `www.foo.com` only, same goes for `bar.com`